# Biometric Residence permit

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, family

I am married with EEA husband and I have been issued a residence card by the Greek authorities.  My husband is residing in the UK more than 3 months as a worker.  I want to travel to the UK with my husband.  Do I need an entry visa or can I travel just with my residence card?

Answer (score 1):

You can travel without a visa if all of the following are true:

- Your residence card states that it is a residence card of the family member of an EEA national.
- You can show evidence at the border of your relationship to your husband.
- You can show evidence at the border that your husband is in the UK.

The last item can also be satisfied by traveling with your husband.

In addition, it's possible that the immigration officer might ask for

- Evidence that your husband is working in the UK (because he has been there for longer than three months), or
- Evidence that your husband is in fact an EEA national.

If you are joining your husband, that is, if you are not traveling together, it would be best for your husband to be at the airport when you arrive, with a fully charged mobile phone.

Further reading:

[Do I need a visa to visit the UK with my EU partner?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/90032/19400)